# Flutter: Changing page transition in Navigator 2.0

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have a `Router` that works likes this:
In the first step there is a `MaterialPage` being created:

```
return MaterialPage(
      child: SomePage(),
      key: keyName,
      name: pageName,
      arguments: routeSettings.arguments,
    );
```

and added to the array of `Page`s then `notifyListeners()` is called. This router class has a `build` method like this:

```
return Navigator(
      key: navigatorKey,
      pages: List.of(_pages),
      onPopPage: _onPopPage,
    );
```

Now my question is where can change page transition for some pages in such a setting? I was trying to use `page_transition` package but it returns a `PageTransition` object not a `Widget` which is required in `MaterialPage`.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PageRouteBuilder` to implement different page transitions. For example a slide animation:

```
class SlideRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  final RouteSettings settings;
  SlideRoute({required this.page, required this.settings})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              page,
          settings: settings,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              SlideTransition(
            position: Tween<Offset>(
              begin: const Offset(1, 0),
              end: Offset.zero,
            ).animate(animation),
            child: child,
          ),
        );
}
```

Then you can use this when returning a route, for example with `onGenerateRoute` of `MaterialApp`:

```
MaterialApp(
  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case '/route1':
        return SlideRoute(page: Route1(), settings: settings);
      case '/route2':
        return SlideRoute(page: Route2(), settings: settings);
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: It does not work with my settings, is it because I set `router` in the `GetMaterialApp`?

Comment: @Maysam You mean `routes`? Yes, I think you have to set either `routes` or `onGenerateRoute`. For `PageRouteBuilder`  to work try removing `routes` and defining them like in my answer.

Comment: That won't work for me, i need to keep the routes.

Comment: Sorry to hear. Just curiosity: why? Basically one way of defining routes is set `routes` property, and another is `onGenerateRoute`. Behind the scenes these are quite similar. And if you want to insert an animation, I am afraid `routes` is not going to work.

Comment: Because I have a router class to parse and inject required variables and dependencies into the page

Comment: In [this article](https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade) they write about `TransitionDelegate`, maybe it helps you.

Comment: To be clear to anyone reading this, Navigator 2.0 IS the use of a router widget, so this question doesn't answer the question.